# ignore special characters in find and replace command of perl

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I am using this command to perform find and replace

```
system( "perl -pi -e 's/$arr3[$i]/$arr2[$i]/g' /opt/app/d1ebl1m5/dv02/cingbt02/J2EEServer/config/AMSS/application/properties/CSCEnvVar.properties_try");
```

the value of `$arr3[$i]` contains special characters like `-e`, `$` etc. what can I do to ignore all special characters and just treat the expression as normal string

Comment: Using a `system` command to call Perl within Perl is rather inefficient and slow. Especially if this operation is run multiple times, as it seems that it is (looping over `@arr3` and `@arr2`). It would most likely be 10 times faster to just open the files normally.

Answer (score 2):

You normally want

```
my $search_pat = quotemeta($search);    
s/\Q$search_pat\E/$replace/g
```

or the equivalent

```
s/\Q$search\E/$replace/
```

It's usually a bad idea to generate code, so the solution becomes

```
system(
   perl => (
      '-i', '-p',
      '-e' => '
         BEGIN { $s = shift(@ARGV); $e = shift(@ARGV); }
         s/\Q$s/$e/g
      ',
      '--',
      $arr3[$i],
      $arr2[$i],
      '/opt/app/.../CSCEnvVar.properties_try',
   )
);
```

Comment: Is `--` absolutely necessary and shouldn't be `-i => -p =>`?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it will fail if `$arr3[$i]` starts with `-` (which the OP specifically said is possible) // Why? `-p` is not a value for `-i`.

Comment: They should be quoted then as they are system() string arguments.

Comment: @mpapec, Hum, `-i` doesn't need to be quoted, but `-p` does??? `perl -E'use strict; say for -i, -p'`. Fixed.

Comment: `-p` is test for named pipe, and `-e` gets quoted anyway due fat comma . Don't know why `-i` doesn't need quotation. +1, perhaps implicit @ARGV when shifting.

Comment: @mpapec, Unary minus autoquotes like fat comma (which doesn't automquote `-e`, but just `e`). Forgot about -X tests